# Clone value in input field in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

In Meteor, I have an input field

```
<input type="name">
```

and another input field

```
<input type="name2">
```

How can I set the value of the second input field to be the exact same as the first input field, i.e. the value in the second input field should also be a clone of the value in the first input field?

Comment: can be done in 1 line of code. what have you tried ?

Comment: Have tried creating a reactive var and update this reactive var with a keyup event

Comment: well, you can just put `'keyUp [name=name]': function(event) { $('[name=name2]').val(event.target.value)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
<input type="name" id="first">
<input type="name2" value={{val}}>

Tempalte.example.events({
  'keypress #first':function(event, template){
      Template.instance().inputVal.set($(event.target).val());
  }
})

Template.example.helpers({
 val: function(){
   return Template.instance().inputVal.get();
 }
});

Template.example.onCreated(function(){
   var self = this;
   self.inputVal = new ReactiveVar();
});
```